# Mine craft launcher turns grey when I attempt to load it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos, minecraft-launcher

I’ve recently bought a brand new MacBook and I bought Minecraft from the official site too, everything was working smoothly up until a few days ago.

Now, whenever I go to click on the grass block to open Minecraft launcher where I’d go a click the play button, it simply just turns grey and doesn’t respond for ages.

I’ve tried everything, I’ve deleted the game entirely multiple times and nothing is fixing it.

Comment: Have you installed any special software? Which MacBook?

Answer (score 1):

**If your launcher is stuck or "Not responding", please try the following fix:**

> 1. Close the game & launcher
> 2. Press ⌘ Command + Space
> 3. Type `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft` and click on "minecraft" under "Folders"
> 4. Delete `launcher_msa_credentials(.json)`
> 5. Try to play the game again